# Laravel Unit Testing Inconsistency

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5

Hi I am following the laravel course from [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/22), but faced some difficulty following the course.

In the app, there is a Post Model with a static function that returns grouped records:

**Post.php**

```
public static function archives()
{

    return static::selectRaw('year(created_at) as year, monthname(created_at) month, count(*) published')
    ->groupBy('year', 'month')
    ->orderByRaw('min(created_at) desc')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
}
```

On the other hand, a test case aims to test the Post::archives() function:

**ExampleTest.php**

```
public function testBasicTest()
{

    // GIVEN I have two records in the database that are posts,
    // and each one is posted a month apart.
    $first = factory(Post::class)->create();

    $second = factory(Post::class)->create([
       'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth()
    ]);
    // WHEN I fetch the archives
    $posts = \App\Post::archives();
    // dd($posts);
    // THEN the response should be in the proper format
    $this->assertEquals([
        [
            "year" => $first->created_at->format('Y'),
            "month" => $first->created_at->format('F'),
            "published" => 1
        ],
        [
            "year" => $first->created_at->format('Y'),
            "month" => $first->created_at->format('F'),
            "published" => 1
        ],
    ], $posts);
}
```

However, the assertion failed, because $posts is an array of object instead of an array of array, even though `Post::archives()` specifically converted the results with `toArray()`.

Dumping it on tinker:

```
$posts = \App\Post::archives()
[
 [
   "year" => 2014,
   "month" => "March",
   "published" => 2,
 ],
 [
   "year" => 2014,
   "month" => "February",
   "published" => 1,
 ],
 [
   "year" => 2013,
   "month" => "February",
   "published" => 1,
 ],
]
```

**The error on phpunit**

```
1) Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::testBasicTest
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
-    0 => Array (...)
-    1 => Array (...)
+    0 => App\Post Object (...)
+    1 => App\Post Object (...)
 )
```

**dd($posts) derives:-**

```
    ..array:2 [
  0 => App\Post {#863
    #guarded: []
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:3 [
      "year" => 2018
      "month" => "April"
      "published" => 1
    ]
    #original: array:3 [
      "year" => 2018
      "month" => "April"
      "published" => 1
    ]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
  }
  1 => App\Post {#864
    #guarded: []
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:3 [
      "year" => 2018
      "month" => "March"
      "published" => 1
    ]
    #original: array:3 [
      "year" => 2018
      "month" => "March"
      "published" => 1
    ]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
  }
]
```

Why is it behaving as such in the TestCase?

Comment: no that's not the case assertEquals mean it must be identical even the order of rows must be same

Comment: @bader i was just proving that Post::archives() is returning an Array of Array. I will include the actual test fail for clarity.

Comment: What are you testing ? It seems you're trying to test that the arrays returned are the same, but they're actually not.

Comment: I think you are using an old version of Laravel I've tested it on 5.6 and got list of an arrays

Comment: @SteveChamaillard i am following the lesson in laracast. I am aware they are different. Because when called outside test case, Post::archives() returns array of array; when called inside test case, Post::archives() returns array of objects. I want to know why

Comment: @bader im using Laravel Framework 5.6.15 and PHPUnit 7.0.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Comment: you are using mysql in PHPUnit ?

Comment: yes. is that a problem?

Comment: try sqlite although it won't work with that mysql select raw you maybe need to change it a bit just to check if the mysql is the main issue

Comment: @bader same results...

Comment: I'm an advocate of never unit testing with a live DB, but this is insane. What happens if you remove the `->toArray()`? Do you still get a `Post` object or do you then suddenly get a `Collection` object as return value? There's also a little bug btw, you use `$first->created_at` in both your arrays.

Comment: @Loek removing the ->toArray() will give me a `Collection` object. Appreciate the bug prompt, but it is irrelevant in this case.. Right now it's a separate MySQL test DB with RefreshDatabase module in the Unit Testing, is there any other way to test it, considering the production uses MySQL as well?

Comment: Unit testing is all about testing at function level, and thus a DB has absolutely nothing to do with it (although opinions differ!). You can always mock a return value for the `archives()` function, or maybe write an integration test. Nevertheless, the fact that it returns a `Collection` object baffles me...

Answer (score 0):

While it might be extra labor, and I can't exactly tell you why it happens, you might want to explicitly call the attributes in an outside array, as in:

```
$postsArray = [
    "year" => $posts->year,
    "month" => $posts->month,
    "published" => $posts->published
];
```

I think the reason it is doing that is because it first creates the model object and then attempts to access the query search, and for whatever reason it simply returns the object instance. I would need to read a little more before giving a good conclusion. I was going to say that it might just be failing to find anything with the query and thus returning the object itself, but I haven't actually ever used a model search that way so I can't say with precision that's what happens.